# SQL: Group a Union

Tags: mysql, group-by, union

I have the following query that always give me two rows. I want to group them to one row using `tbluser.userid`, is it possible to group a union?

```
SELECT
SUM(tblfooditem.calories)
FROM tblfooditem
INNER JOIN tbluser ON tblfooditem.userid = tbluser.userid
WHERE tblfooditem.userid=?userid AND tblfooditem.date=?date
GROUP BY tbluser.userid
UNION
SELECT
SUM(tbladdedmealitem.calories)
FROM tbladdedmeal
INNER JOIN tbluser ON tbladdedmeal.userid = tbluser.userid
WHERE tbladdedmeal.userid=?userid AND tbladdedmeal.date=?date
GROUP BY tbluser.userid;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible.

```
select sum(s) from (
SELECT
    SUM(tblfooditem.calories) S,tbl.userid
    FROM tblfooditem
    INNER JOIN tbluser ON tblfooditem.userid = tbluser.userid
    WHERE tblfooditem.userid=?userid AND tblfooditem.date=?date
    GROUP BY tbluser.userid
    UNION
    SELECT
    SUM(tbladdedmealitem.calories) S,tbl.userid
    FROM tbladdedmeal
    INNER JOIN tbluser ON tbladdedmeal.userid = tbluser.userid
    WHERE tbladdedmeal.userid=?userid AND tbladdedmeal.date=?date
    GROUP BY tbluser.userid
) Q
group by Q.userid
```